# why my trap doesn't work when the signal set as "DEBUG" fake signal?

Tags: linux, debugging, bash, shell, ubuntu

```
#test code:

#!/bin/bash
#~/test/test.sh
trap "echo 'testmessage'" DEBUG

while :
do
echo abc
sleep 6
done
```

---

```
#run it
~/test$sh test.sh
```

==============================

```
#result
=>   trap: DEBUG: bad trap
```

==============================

?[shell debug] why my trap doesn't work when the signal set as "DEBUG" fake signal,but report trap error?

Comment: It works for me. What version of Bash?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bash? Shebang needs to be on the very first line of your script. Your prompt seems to imply you're using a non-bash sh. `DEBUG` trap works even in Bash POSIX mode (though of course, it shouldn't be used there).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message "bad trap" is produced by ash, not bash. When you run `sh test.sh` the shebang line is irrelevant because you aren't executing the script, you're executing the program called "sh" with "test.sh" as an argument. The sh program (in your case a symlink to ash or dash, I bet) then does its best to run the script named in the argument. The shebang line would come into play if you ran the command `./test.sh` (it'll need +x permission first).